# Facebook Places Search using Client Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

[This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/access-tokens) claims that you can access the Places Graph functionality without having a logged-in user:

> You make your calls using a Client Token (from the client), and an App Access Token (from the server).

[The documentation regarding Client Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) says:

> The client token is an identifier that you can embed into native mobile binaries or desktop apps to identify your app. The client token isn't meant to be a secret identifier because it's embedded in apps.

This sounds like exactly what I want--I am trying to build a website that allows users to search for Facebook places. I need to be able to build the list using an AJAX request from the client side.

I can't for the life of me find any documentation on *using* the Client Token to make such a request.

Please note that I **cannot** use an App Token because this will be deployed to a website, and Facebook specifically says not to use App Tokens in that context.

I've tried using the Client Token directly as the `access_token`, but then I get `Invalid OAuth access token.`

How can I use the Client Token to make a Places Graph API call directly to Facebook's API from the client's browser?

*Note: I realize that I could send the request to my own server, then relay that request from my server to Facebook, but that is not an optimal solution for me.*

Comment: Is a website a native mobile binary or desktop app …? No, so that is not really applicable here in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe the website in question is a hybrid app. Technically no, it's not a binary or desktop app, but that's just semantics. It's called a Client Token because it identifies your app when deployed to the client. To me, that means it doesn't really matter what language I'm using to write "the application" or whether that language compiles down to native code or not. Google APIs have options designed for this purpose, which restrict API keys to browser use and enforce Referrer fields; the Client Token from Facebook seems to be the same sort of thing.

Comment: Still I doubt whether that will work though, not too sure if you can use Facebook Login features with the Website platform, when you declare your app a desktop app in the settings ... you'd have to try.

Comment: I did try (at least the efforts I stated in the question), and for what it's worth the "Native or desktop app?" toggle in my advanced settings is set to NO, the only Platform listed under basic settings is Website, and it still provides me a Client Token. That and the documentation from the first link is what made me think this was possible. The word "and" in the first quote is a bit disheartening though.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/ios mentions using the client token with the iOS SDK, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/android mentions using it with the Android SDK, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web - doesn't mention client token at all. I am pretty sure this is something the SDKs add to the outgoing API requests somehow, but probably hashed/encrypted or otherwise obscured. Never have I seen it mentioned as something you can add yourself directly to API calls made using their JS SDK or other client-side web technologies.

Comment: It's interesting, because the third link you provided is the one I've been using to put this together--and it doesn't mention anything about *any* kind of tokens (App or Client). Obviously one is required, because the requests fail without it. However, they don't provide any instructions or documentation relating to that aspect of it. I think the documentation might still be a work in progress, since they talk about adding the SDK to your iOS app, in the Android section. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153506/discussion-between-eric-lindsey-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still struggling with this like I was.  You just need to use the appId and client token joined with a pipe.  So "appId|clientToken".

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue described in the question. I was getting error code 33. Now, by concatenating the appId with the clientToken I get error code 190... response.getErrorMessage(): Invalid access token signature. Have you ever solved it? Thank you